# Fetching Controller Name on Model in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How to fetch the controller name on model in Rails?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Really, you shouldn't be handling controllers in the model, which is why I ask...

Answer (score 3):

Why do you want to do that? It completely violates the Model/View/Controller architecture because models should have no knowledge of controllers. Controllers know about models, not the other way around.

If you tell us the problem you're trying to solve then we might be able to suggest a better alternative. Is it this one? [Skipping before Create on particular controller alone in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920437/skipping-before-create-on-particular-controller-alone-in-rails)

Comment: Ya that one need to skip before_create on the controller which i am using create method on that